# PHP Fatal error: Class simplexml_load_string not found

Tags: php, fatal-error, simplexml

I am trying to read soap result in php 5.3.3 on linux machine but get the error:

> Fatal error: Class simplexml_load_string not found

I have php-xml installed.

Oddly enough, using SimpleXMLElement does not cause an error.

Comment: Show your code.... `simplexml_load_string` is a function, not a class so I hope you're not trying to do `new simplexml_load_string()`

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do ... make that your answer and I'll check mark it.

Comment: are you sure you need a `new` keyword?